# how to apply background transparency on a div (for an AJAX loading animation)?

Tags: css

I've been browsing for a watch as a present to someone and I came across an ajax loading I'm trying to replicate.

1. I got most of it working (via looking at the CSS) except, I cannot simulate the dark/transparency happening when the ajax animation is displayed. Any ideas how it could be done?
2. Also Any ideas on how can I make the clock "glow"? And the color inside it white?

This is the website: http://www.jomashop.com/tissot.html?gender=25&price_filter=23789. To make the animation appear, change the price.

here's the full code I'm working on:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#ajax-loader{
    display: block;
    border-radius: 60px;
    border: 6px solid #414C5C;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    background-image:none!important;
    background:#fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #FFF;
}

#ajax-loader::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #414C5C;
    top:6px;
    left: 48%;
    height: 35px;
    width: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 94%;
            transform-origin: 50% 94%;
    -webkit-animation: ptAiguille 12s linear infinite;
            animation: ptAiguille 12s linear infinite;
}

#ajax-loader::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #414C5C;
    top:2px;
    left: 48%;
    height: 38px;
    width: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 97%;
            transform-origin: 50% 97%;
    -webkit-animation: grdAiguille 2s linear infinite;
            animation: grdAiguille 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes grdAiguille{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes ptAiguille{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}


#page-overlay {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 1000001; // or, higher
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

</style>
<body>
<p>testest sdfdsf sfs sdfsd sdfds f sdfsdf sfsdf s sdfsdfdsfsdf  sdfsdfsd</p>
<div id="ajax-loader"></div>
<div id="page-overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an overlay `div` at the end of your HTML and try adding the following CSS to your overlay `div`:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 1000001; // or, higher
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

This would create a shaded transparent layer preventing you from clicking the back.

UPDATE: To apply the glow effect, add an image within your overlay `div` (with a class, lets say `loading`) and apply the following CSS to the image:

```
img.loading
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
```

Comment: any way to get the animation "glow" like in the link? also the the middle of the clock is white? how do I do that? thanks a lot :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The element they are using to provide the overlay is `#backgroundPopup`.  If you look at the element css you will see that the `opacity` is set to 0.7.  This allows a 30% transparency on the element, and is being triggered by javascript to show/hide the div - by default it is hidden.

```
element.style {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#backgroundPopup {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999998;
}
```

Using the same technique you can get this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/j3uhnf03/1/